# Monitor Global keyboard input on a Mac with python

Tags: python, macos, input, keyboard

Trying to write a program that allows users to control a program via global shortcuts. I already have a working version on windows using pyHook but can't figure out how to capture global input on a Mac. The other questions I have read here so far mostly seemed to be about Linux not Mac. (which is why I'm asking) Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use [`PyObjC`](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/pyobjc.html) to handle the API hooks; look at [this explanation](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/02/24/hotkeys_framework2/) for what to do.